# What sets are known to have cardinality equal to $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ but open as to which?

Tags: big-list, gm.general-mathematics

A long time ago a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814072/are-there-any-infinite-sets-that-are-not-known-to-be-either-countable-or-uncount) was asked on math.stackexchange.

There are many sets which we know to be either finite or infinitely countable but do not know which cardinality specifically.

An example that comes to mind is the set of twin primes. But comparing countably infinite vs cardinality of the continuum I can't really come up with any "natural looking" examples (or any examples for that matter to be frank).

As a result I'm interested in organizing a community wiki to keep track of sets for which we haven't yet settled if the cardinality is countably infinite or the same as the continuum but we do know that it must be one of the two.

Comment: Non-natural example: the closure in $\mathbf{Z}_p$ of the union of the set of twin primes.

Comment: $\mathbb N\cup\{x\in\mathbb R:\text{the Riemann hypothesis holds}\}$.

Comment: Your title is about the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ vs. the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$, while your main text is about "countable vs. uncountable". These are not the same thing, so please clarify your question.

Comment: I have clarified the question, when I had written “countable” earlier I meant “countably infinite” or “cardinality of the natural numbers”. Similarly when I had written uncountable earlier I meant “cardinality of the continuum”

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal: but then this is not at all "the same question" as the one you link to on MSE.

Comment: I have edited my post to reflect the earlier question had a similar spirit but was not the same

Comment: The number of twin [hypernatural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinteger) primes.

Comment: The sentence "There are many sets which we do not know to be either finite or infinitely countable but do know it’s one of the two" contradicts itself.

Comment: I have updated the sentence to something hopefully a little clearer

Comment: Borel's conjecture on [Strong Measure Zero Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_measure_zero_set) comes to mind. Is that the kind of answer you want?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais yea that seems like a perfect match, it looks like we also have made enough progress to know its independent of ZFC as opposed to merely being an open problem